# After i set theme as Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar my button corner radius looks in White in .NET Maui

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui, .net-8.0

after setting theme as Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar facing issues with my Button control's appearance in White on the corners of the button.

Environment: .NET Maui with targetting .NET 8,
Platform: Android

```
<Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="20" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" CornerRadius="40" ></Button>
```

[image: Corner showing as white]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. It appears to be a bug, you can report it on the repo.

And for the workaround, you can use the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge` instead of `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`.

The [Getting started with Material Components for Android in the Android docs](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started) said:

> If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you can inherit from a Material Components Bridge theme.

But the button's text position was wrong when I used `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge`. So you can add the following code in the App.cs to center the button's text.

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Button), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
#endif
        });
```